# why my response.body is empty and my device token in my backend is null?

Tags: laravel, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am Using Laravel for my App backend and want to send push notification to my flutter app
my question is why response body is empty and device token in the backend is null?

```
static Future<http.Response> sendDeviceToken(String FCM_token) async{

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int id=sharedPreferences.getInt("id");
    String myUrl = "$serverUrl/FCM";
    var resp = await http.post(Uri.encodeFull(myUrl),
      headers: <String, String>{
        "Accept": "application/json",
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'FCM_token': FCM_token,
        'id' : id.toString(),
      }),
    );
    print("res.statusCode: ${resp.statusCode}");
    print("res.body: ${resp.body}");
    return resp;
  }
```

i print FCM_token inside this function and it print correct.

Comment: You are capturing the token correctly, just send it to your backend, it's a string. Send it with the user ID and store them, then you can use them to send notifications to this device.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @HuthaifaMuayyad ;-)

Comment: As always, lots of love @FrankvanPuffelen <3

Answer (score 1):

You are capturing the FCM token correctly, just send it to your backend using a post method, and be prepared on your backend to capture this post. The FCMtoken is a string.

You can also send it along with the user ID for example, store them, then you can use them to send notifications to this user, because you have the userId and their device's FCMtoken.

Comment: how can i send it by using post method? @Huthaifa

Comment: Send it to your server, so your server can store it in your database. Write a simple `post` request from your flutter app. If you don't know how to do that, that is where I advise you to start looking :)

[check here.](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data)

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Where is the problem?

Comment: resp.body print empty and in the backend the value is null